# Show trailing spaces in HTML report field

Tags: c#, html, css, vb.net

1. I am trying to create an email HTML report
2. Some of the values in the report have trailing spaces
3. I want to highlight the values that have a trailing space

The value gets highlighted but not the trailing space.

This is what I tried so far.

```
HTMLReport.Append('<td align='left' valign='top'><span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>')
HTMLReport.Append(.value)
HTMLReport.Append('</span></td>')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&nbsp;` instead of space. If you have a variable you want to concatenate, substitute spaces like this:

```
myValue.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

Another approach is to use tables and cells with background color to achieve the effect.